# How can I implement a v-radio-group with nullable boolean items?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to have 3 radio buttons which values are `true, false and null`. But when I set the value to null, it does not work and the item with null value is not selected But if I use values `[1, 2, 3]` instead of that, it works. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that vuetify does not allow `null` (as well as exact duplicates) by default. For this you can just use by using v-model.
I created a sandbox to show it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dijkstra-ndvvi?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that they do not support null value. Did they mention that on their website?